# Why can I not have multiple aws provider versions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm trying to create a configuration that supports multiple provider versions like so
https://github.com/qzhang1/Terraform-Multi-Provider-Example

But I keep running into this error on init:

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/aws versions matching "<= 4.16.*, 3.55.*, 4.16.*"...

Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Could not retrieve the list of available versions for provider hashicorp/aws:
no available releases match the given constraints <= 4.16.*, 3.55.*, 4.16.*
```

Comment: It's not that you can't, it's more that your version constraints are not compatible.

Comment: Also, if you add the code you use, there might be an answer that will help you fix it.

Comment: @MarkoE I left the link to the github repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Terraform a provider is a whole-configuration object, because all modules in a configuration typically share the same provider configuration or set of provider configurations, which internally means they are all literally using the same running program that has the provider configuration loaded into it.

Therefore all modules in your configuration must be able to agree on at least one available version of each provider to use across all of them. In your case you seem to have three different modules that are all being very specific about which provider versions they are compatible with.

If those modules truly do require only the provider versions they are selecting then there will be no way to use these modules together in the same configuration. However, if these modules are just being *unnecessarily specific* (that is: they are excluding provider versions that they would actually work with) then the answer would be to loosen those requirements to more accurately describe what each module requires.

A typical guideline for shared modules (that is, modules designed for use via `module` blocks) is to specify only a *lower bound* -- a `>=` constraint -- for the earliest version you know that the module works with. You should not typically set an *upper bound* on a version constraint unless you *already know* that the module is not compatible with a specific newer version.

The `hashicorp/aws` provider did include some significant changes to the S3-related resource types in major version 4, and so it might actually be true that two of your modules are not compatible with versions `>= 4.0.0`. If that is true then you'll need to either choose or create new versions of those module that are compatible with the latest versions of the provider if you want to use them with modules that require major version 4.